# Maintaining uniqueness of records

Tags: oracle, vb6, uniqueidentifier

There are almost 3 million financial transaction records in my database. These records are loaded from external files containing following fields which are mapped to the table's columns.

```
Account, Date, Amount, Particulars/Description/Details/Narration
```

Now There is a need to maintain uniqueness of already loaded and future records.

Since there was no uniqueness in external files which are already loaded so, I think, we have to update existing records by making unique key using given fields, but, it is quite clear that fields in the external file may duplicate.

How to maintain such uniqueness that we can identify a transactions from the file is already loaded. All type of suggestions are welcome.

**Edit 1**

Currently loaded records are confirmed to be valid, the need to maintain uniqueness has just came up due to loading of some missing records from older files or missing files

**Edit 2**

Existing records may have duplicate records based on given 4 fields i.e. same values for Account, Date, Amount and Particulars for two or more valid transactions, but it is sure that these records are valid even with duplicate values.

Now for loading missing records we need to identify if a record is already loaded or not so that we don't load a record which is already loaded. So, to me, it looks very hard to know if a record is already loaded based on these fields. I see it as beyond the limits of these fields

**Edit 3**

**Situation has changed now and this is no more a valid question but it would be better to keep it here for others. It has been agreed to add a unique key in records and hence check against this key for duplication**

Answer (score 1):

**Note**  - following some clarification from the OP this answer is not relevant to their scenario.  The problem is a political or business problem rather than a technical one.  I will leave this answer as a solution to a hypothetical question because it may still be of use to some future seekers.

[My other response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17542659/146325)  addresses the OP's actual situation.

---

It seems like you need a compound unique key:

```
alter table your_table add constraint your_table_uk
    unique (Account, Date, Amount, Particulars)
    using index
```

`particulars`  seems a bit woolly as a source of uniqueness, but presumably an account can have more than one transaction for the same amount on any given day, so you need all four columns to guarantee uniqueness of the row.

Or perhaps, as @ypercube suggests, only `(Account, Date, Particulars)` are necessary.

I have suggested a unique key rather than a primary key constraint because composite primary keys are bad news when it comes to enforcing foreign keys.  In this case I would suggest you add a synthetic primary key, populated with a sequence.

You say the loaded records have a proven validity, but if that is not the case change the ALTER TABLE statement to use the EXCEPTIONS INTO clause to find the duplicated rows.   You will a special table to capture the constraint violations.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general005.htm#ADMIN11553).

Comment: or perhaps the 3 columns - without the `Amount`.

Comment: Not possible, as i have stated that these columns can simply be duplicated for two or more valid transactions

Comment: @ypercube - perhaps.  But without seeing the data who can tell?

Comment: I agree. I have no idea what Particulars means anyway. But it makes some sense (to me, not sure if it's correct without looking at the data) that in a transaction, the amount does not identify it.

Comment: @bjan - you have not clearly stated anything.  Are you saying you have already loaded *duplicate rows* and you want to keep them?  So all you want is some meaningless UID?

Comment: @ypercube - given the OP's subsequent comment I'm not sure what the role of "sense" is in this data model ;)

Comment: @APC Yes; partially, not sure. Please see Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

> "Existing records may have duplicate records based on given 4 fields
>   i.e. same values for Account, Date, Amount and Particulars for two or
>   more valid transactions, but it is sure that these records are valid
>   even with duplicate values."

But how can anybody tell, if there is no token of uniqueness in the loaded data or the source files?  What does validity even mean?

> "Now for loading missing records we need to identify if a record is
>   already loaded or not so that we don't load a record which is already
>   loaded."

Without an existing source of uniqueness you cannot do this.  Because it you have two rows for a given combination of `(Account, Date, Amount, Particulars)` and that's okay, what are the rules for determining that a third instance of (Account, Date, Amount, Particulars) is a record which which has already been loaded, hence invalid, or record which has not been loaded, hence valid.

> "So, to me, it looks very hard to know if a record is already loaded
>   based on these fields. I see it as beyond the limits of these fields"

You're right to say that the solution cannot be found in the data as you describe it.  But the solution is actually very simple.  You go to the people who have asserted the validity of the loaded records and present them with a list of these additional records.  They'll be able to use their skill and judgement to tell you which records are valid, and you load those.

---

> " it is my duty to find the solution"

No it is not your duty.  Right now the duty lies on the shoulders of the data owner to define their data set accurately, and that includes identifying a business key.  They are the ones abrogating their responsibilities.

Under the circumstances you have three choices:

1. Refuse to load any further records until the data owner does their duty.
2. Load all the records presented to you for loading, without any validation.
3. Use the horrible NOVALIDATE syntax.

NOVALIDATE is a way of enforcing validation rules for future rows but ignoring violations in the existing data.  Basically it's a technical kludge for a political problem.

```
SQL> select * from t23
     /

      COL1 COL2
---------- --------------------
         1 MR KNOX
         1 MR KNOX
         2 FOX IN SOCKS
         2 FOX IN SOCKS


SQL> create index t23_idx on t23(col1,col2)
     /

Index created.

SQL> alter table t23 add constraint t23_uk 
          unique (col1,col2) novalidate
     /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t23 values (2, 'FOX IN SOCKS')
      /

insert into t23 values (2, 'FOX IN SOCKS')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_UK) violated

SQL>
```

Note that you need to pre-create a non-unique index before adding the constraint.  If you don't do that the database will build a unique index and that will override the NOVALIDATE clause.

I describe the NOVALIDATE as horrible because it is.  It bakes data corruption into the database.  But it is the closest thing you'll get to a solution.

This approach completely ignores the notion of "validity".  So it will reject records which perhaps should have loaded because they represent a "valid" nth occurrence of  `(Account, Date, Amount, Particulars)`.  This is unavoidable.  The good news is, nobody will be able to tell, because there are no defined rules for establishing validity.

Whatever option you choose, it is crucial that you explain it clearly to your boss, the data owner, the data owner's boss and whoever else you think fit, and get *their written  assent* to go ahead.  Otherwise, sometime down the line people will discover that the database is full of duplicate rows or somebody will complain that a "valid" record hasn't been loaded, and it will all be your fault ... unless you have a signed piece of paper with authorisation from the appropriate top brass.

Good luck

---

[Haki's suggestion of using MERGE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17542715/146325) has the same effect as NOVALIDATE, because it would load new records and suppress all duplicates.  However, it is even more of a kludge: it doesn't address the notion of uniqueness at all.  Anybody who had INSERT or UPDATE access would still be able to have any rows they liked.  So this approach would only work if you could completely lock down privileges on that table so that its data can only be manipulated through MERGE and no other DML.  Depends whether ongoing uniqueness matters.  Again, a business decision.

Comment: "go to the people who have asserted the validity of the loaded records", you are right so far :) but it is my duty to find the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need an upsert - or as oracle calls it [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

A `MERGE` operation between two tables allows you to handle two common situations -

1. The record already exist in the target table and I need to do
   something with it - either update or do nothing.
2. The record does not exist in the target table - Insert it.